# Text in anchor tag exceeds div width

Tags: html

I have div tag with fixed height. in it there is anchor tag < a> tag. when text in anchor tag exceeds width of div it comes in 2 lines in div tag. Due height of div tag second line is displayed half. so how to use text-overflow :ellipsis so that ellipsis will be displayed and with which tag? please help.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need a single line of text, you can set the `white-space` CSS property to `nowrap`. The complete CSS will look as follows:

```
div {
    width: 75px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}​
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yXgQT/